# Python-ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: php, python, linux, selenium, linux-mint

I tried to import selenium on python and it didnt let me.
I am using linux mint. I checked that it was installing selenium in ./anaconda3... and i moved it into /etc/ but still doesn't recognize it.
What can I do?

```
>>> import selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a list of paths (directories/folders) it searches for modules to import. You can see the list by doing:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

If you install a module using your system's package manager, it ought to land in one of those paths. If you want Python to search somewhere else, you can add to that list via the system environment variable, `PYTHONPATH`.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/etc/python/whyhere/
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/etc/python/whyhere', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Or,

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/etc/python/whyhere/ python
>>> ...
```

The best thing to do is ensure the module is installed properly to a "good" path. If that's not possible, change your PYTHONPATH. A messier approach is to directly append to `sys.path`, ie `sys.path.append('/etc/mypath')` but that's not very clean.